# Forward variable declaration in C++

Tags: c++

I know what "*forward function declaration*" means, but I want get the same with variables.

I have this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int x;

int main()
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;   // I want get printed "2" but I get compile error

    return 0;
}

**x = 2;**
```

In the `std::cout` I want print "2" value, but trying to compile this I get this compile error:  **error: 'x' does not name a type**.

While this doesn't appear somthing of programmatically impossible, I can't compile successfully.

So what is the right form to write this and obtain a forward variable declaration?

Comment: Assignment is different from initialization. It simply cannot be done outside of function scope.

Comment: The question is not specific for the building tools (CMake, Visual Studio). Why do you add them as tags?

Answer (score 2):

Variable declarations need `extern`. Variable definitions need the type, like declarations. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

extern int x;

int main()
{
    std::cout << x << '\n';
}

int x = 2;
```

Normally you'd use `extern` to access a variable from a different translation unit (i.e. from a different `.cpp` file), so this is mostly an artifical example.

Comment: Ok this works, but I read "extern" keyword makes the "x" variale will be visible in other .cpp files, so my question is how can get the same result as you mentioned but keeping only a file-scope, avoiding other cpp files can see the "x" variable?

Comment: @AlessiaCorra It's not because of `extern`; functions and global variables are visible to other files by default. You can use `static` to prevent that, but it seems it can't be combined with `extern`, so this might be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare

```
extern int x;
```

in this file, and in some other file

```
int x = 2;
```

Comment: Ok this works, but I read "extern" keyword makes the "x" variale will be visible in other .cpp files, so my question is how can get the same result as you mentioned but keeping only a file-scope, avoiding other cpp files can see the "x" variable?

Comment: I guess you can hide it with anonymous namespace... What exactly are you trying to achieve? There might be an easier / more straight-forward way

Answer (score 0):

You could use Class and declare variable inside. Also, anonymous namespace is  needed as Vlad said. Example:

```
#include<iostream>
namespace 
{
    class MyClass
    {
    public:
        static int x;
    };
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << MyClass::x;
}

int MyClass::x = 2;
```